# How to handle the errors during libwebkitgtk installation on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package

Every time I tries to install something on Ubuntu using `sudo apt-get install ...`, it shows like that:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 : Depends: libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 (= 2.32.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 2.32.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

First I tried to `sudo apt-get install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37`, it shows like that:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libexiv2-14 libgee-0.8-2 libgexiv2-2 libraw16 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-66
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-67 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-73
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-74 shotwell-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 206 not upgraded.
43 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/13.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 81.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-sil-abyssinica' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libatk-adaptor:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libvorbisfile3:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libquadmath0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxkbfile1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

<ignoring for a long long list>

Preparing to unpack .../libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37_2.32.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.32.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (2.32.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37_2.32.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.53.5' to '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.53.5.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37_2.32.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I thought that since it says `but 2.32.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed`, so I tries uninstalling it using `sudo apt-get purge 2.32.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`, and things goes like that: (I don't know what the `2.32.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1` means)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package 2.32.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '2.32.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex '2.32.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'
```

And I tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, but it still doesn't works. The error messages are the same as that when I run `sudo apt-get install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37`.

Could someone help me out? Any reply is in fervent anticipation.

Platform: x64, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Have you tried what the apt message is saying? You might want to run 'sudo apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it. I've updated the question and it still not works.